# decreased digits of a numbers until get one-digit number

Tags: vb.net

I tried to make a function that would subtract from a number, for example number `25`, to display the result `3` (because `5-2=3`) - the `smallest` is subtracted from the `large` number - while the numbers from `1` to `9` will remain the same so it will take into account only what is of 2 digits. unfortunately I kind of failed in my attempt and I would need a little help.

```
Dim lines As String() = originalString.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))

            For Each line As String In lines

                Dim lineSum As String = 0
                Dim index As Integer = 0
                Dim numchars1 As Char
                Dim numchars2 As Char

                For Each numberChar As Char In line

                    index += 1

                    If index = 1 Then
                        numchars1 = numberChar
                    End If

                    If index >= 2 Then
                        numchars2 = numberChar
                    End If

                Next

                If Val(numchars1) AndAlso Val(numchars2) > 0 Then

                    If Val(numchars2) > Val(numchars1) Then

                        lineSum = Val(numchars2) - Val(numchars1)

                    ElseIf Val(numchars1) > Val(numchars2) Then

                        lineSum = Val(numchars1) - Val(numchars2)

                    End If

                Else

                    lineSum = numchars1

                End If
```

Comment: What is the subtraction result of `"555"`, is it -5?

Comment: it should go for 2 digits, up to 99. normally it would not work correctly for more than 2 digits. the result would be with - would sometimes give results with a -, yes, it's the same type of exercise but with -, and I'm still trying to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
Public Shared Function Subtract(number As String) As Int32?
    If Not number.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then Return Nothing
    Dim allNumbers As Int32() = number.Select(Function(c) CInt(Char.GetNumericValue(c))).ToArray()
    Dim highest = allNumbers.Max()
    Return highest - (allNumbers.Sum() - highest)
End Function
```

Note that the result of "555" will be -5, because 5 - 5 - 5

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you take the absolute value of the difference, you get the number you want:

```
Function AbsDiff(num As String) As Integer
    Dim a = Convert.ToInt32(num(0))
    Dim b = Convert.ToInt32(num(1))

    Return Math.Abs(a - b)

End Function
```

You may or may not want to check for valid data in the function or before passing it to the function.